# jQuery/Javascript force / pressure on the mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

I was wondering if is there any way to get the pressure level (pressure user makes on clicking on mouse key/button) on click. 
Any resource or links?

Sorry for my bad english, hope my question is clear and hope is not just utopia!

Comment: What do you mean by pressure level?

Comment: the pressure user makes clicking on the mouse key

Comment: Not from a standard mouse as this is not measured. It may be possible from a touch sensitive tablet device though.

Comment: Normally, the mouse has no idea about the pressure used to click its button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse (hardware) doesn't register how hard you click it, and javascript can't track something that doesn't exist.

Comment: What if the user has a mouse that _does_ measure the pressure?

Comment: eheh i was scared about answers like this :) so it's just utopia

Comment: and even if a trackpad registers it, it is not exposed by the Browser via JavaScript. Propably it is not even exposed by the trackpad driver to the OS

Comment: @Fender The Synaptics touchpad driver has a utility that shows the "pressure" (off / very little / anything else)

Comment: @JanDvorak I know but it is "part" of the driver.

Comment: if no api available for also devices which supports the click pressure, i can flag tis as the answer

Answer (score 6):

*I realize that I'm bumping an old thread with something that wasn't relevant then, but I believe this will be useful to others in the future.*

As many others on this thread have pointed out, almost all computer mice don't measure the pressure used, so you cannot measure it. **However**, there are different pointing devices than mice out there, like drawing tablets or trackpads. In Gecko-based browsers like Firefox, there is the non-standard `mozPressure` attribute on mouse events. You would use it sort of like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.mozPressure);
});
```

`mozPressure` is a value between 0.0 and 1.0 depending on how hard the mouse was depressed. If you're using a normal mouse or something else that doesn't detect pressure, then this will always be 0.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly not a qustion about phisical pressure but a measure of how long the user is keeping mouse button down and increasing frequency of some effect based on that information. This is my take:

```
someButton.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.button == 0) {
        someRelevantParentContainer.mouse0Pressed = true;
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
            someRelevantParentContainer.mouse0Pressed = false;
        }, {once : true});
            
        const func = function() {
            if (someRelevantParentContainer.mouse0Pressed && !someButton.disabled) {
                // do something
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        };
        recurAction(func, 200);
    }
});

function recurAction(func, startingTimeout, minTimeout = 50) {
    if (!func()) {
        return;
    }
    if (startingTimeout > minTimeout) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            const cont = func();
            if (cont) {
                recurAction(func, startingTimeout / 1.3);
            }
        }, startingTimeout);
    }
    else {
        const inter = setInterval(function() {
            if (!func()) {
                clearInterval(inter);
            }
        }, minTimeout);
    }
}
```